# Run script if screen size is less than 1024px

Tags: javascript, responsive-design, conditional-statements

I'm running a script on my page that make the `div id="homesplash"` disappear when user scrolls beyond `600px` as follows:

```
$(window).scroll(function() {

    if ($(this).scrollTop()>600)
     {
        $('#homesplash').hide();
     }
    else
     {
      $('#homesplash').show();
     }
 });
```

I need to figure out how to run this script only if the browser width is greater than `1024px`. Any ideas?
I've tried to implement some code from a related post I found here, but I can't get it to work as I am unfamiliar with writing any javascript.
Thanks.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can check `$(window).width()` and compare it to `1024`. Something like:

```
$(window).scroll(function() {
    if ( $(this).width() > 1024 ) {
        $("#homesplash").toggle( $(this).scrollTop() <= 600 );
    }
});
```

Comment: VisioN, am I supposed to replace the previous script with the one you suggest? I don't see any of the "hide" or "show" functions in your script...

Comment: @user820114 Yes, you can use `toggle` instead, it's shorter: http://api.jquery.com/toggle/.

Answer (score 2):

Working with your current code, you could use [$(window).width()](http://api.jquery.com/width/) to get the width:

```
$(window).scroll(function() {

  var windowWidth = $(window).width();

  if (windowWidth > 1024) {
    if ($(this).scrollTop() > 600) {
      $('#homesplash').hide();
    }
    else {
      $('#homesplash').show();
    }
  }

 });
```